# Mousedown event changes the color of child elements even in the bubbling phase

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, event-bubbling, mousedown

I would like to perform a bubbling event for five nested div elements: when I click a div element, the clicked element and its parents should change color.

What I have done in the below code is basically setting "mousedown" element for each and every div element, which will wait for some time for its backgroundColor to change after a mousedown event:

```
const one = document.querySelector("#\\31");
const two = document.querySelector("#\\32");
const three = document.querySelector("#\\33");
const four = document.querySelector("#\\34");
const five = document.querySelector("#\\35");

five.addEventListener(
  "mousedown",
  function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      changeBg(this);
    }, 1500);
  },
  false
);

four.addEventListener(
  "mousedown",
  function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      changeBg(this);
    }, 1750);
  },
  false
);

three.addEventListener(
  "mousedown",
  function (event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      changeBg(this);
    }, 2000);
  },
  false
);

two.addEventListener(
  "mousedown",
  function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      changeBg(this);
    }, 2250);
  },
  false
);

one.addEventListener(
  "mousedown",
  function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      changeBg(this);
    }, 2500);
  },
  false
);

function changeBg(t) {
  const element = document.querySelector("#\\3" + t.id);
  element.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}
```

The issue I've encountered and don't understand is, before changing the color of the clicked div and parent divs, it suddenly changes the color of the child divs(all of them at the same time). Did I miss something in the code, or did I misimplement it as a whole? I'd be so glad if someone can explain it in detail.

Code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-goldstine-ope9w?file=/src/index.js

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to set background color on each `div`. [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-waterfall-gee7w?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thanks, that worked!